# How Can i set large cropper for large images .(react-image-crop)

Tags: reactjs, react-image-crop, image-cropper

I have used react-image-crop (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop) to crop the large image. I need to crop a 1920X726 size image. if I am giving this size for cropper it is adding blank canvas into the image.

Comment: You should include your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Incase not able to crop and image stuck

```js
const pixelRatio = 0.5
```

instead of

```js
const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio
```